# A modular form is holomorphic at $\infty$ means

Tags: modular-forms

I have trouble understanding the definition of the modular forms for the congruence subgroup.
In my text book, the condition "holomorphic at all cusps" is described by :
the Fourier coefficient of $f \vert _k \gamma =\sum a_n q^n$ is $0$ if $n<0.$
For a congruence subgroup $\Gamma$ of level $N$, since it contains $\begin{pmatrix}1&N\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, every modular form $f$ for $\Gamma$ has a period $N$ and hence a Fourier expansion $\sum a_n q_{N}^{n}$ where $q_{N}=e^{2\pi i z/N}.$
My Question is :
Why is the $q$-expansion at $i \infty$ of $f$ is of the form $\sum a_n q^n$? I think that it has to be of the form $\sum a_n q_{N}^{n}$ since it has period $N.$

Comment: What text book are you looking at as if I see the reference I might be able to help. You are right that $f$ will be $N$ periodic, and it might be a typo or just abuse of notation as I have seen people use $q$ even for the $N$ periodic functions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I missed that $\Gamma_{0}(N)$ contains the matrix which maps $z \longmapsto z+1$.